# Nature of the singularity in the Taub-NUT metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, singularities

Consider the Taub-NUT metric

$$ds^2=-V(dt+2N(1-\cos\theta)d\phi)^2+\frac{1}{V}(dr^2)+(r^2+N^2)(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta{}d\phi^2),$$

where $$V=\frac{(r-r_+)(r-r_-)}{(r^2+N^2)} \qquad r_{\pm}=M\pm \sqrt{M^2+N^2}$$

(from Ortin, Gravity and Strings, pag. 376)

See even the background from a similar question, if you need: [Why is the Taub-NUT instanton singular at $\theta=\pi$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121742/why-is-the-taub-nut-instanton-singular-at-theta-pi)

To my knowledge it is not a curvature singularity. Of course the metric is not invertible there (for instance $\det(g)=0$), but this is true even for flat space in spherical coordinates. Can  the singularity be seen as a "place" where the geodesics affine parameter cannot be extended anymore? Can you show me this explicitly? References are welcome.

A potential physical explanation arise in the related problem of Dirac string in magnetic monopoles, where the choice of two patches for the vector potential are needed, in order to have a non vanishing magnetic flux. Is there a similar thing for gravity?

EDIT: I've realized that one could somehow make the analog of the vector potential with the gravitomagnetic potential, for the NUT charge. But this motivation is still unsatisfactory to me.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it *is* a curvature singularity. Note that $d\phi^2$ terms come from the first term, shifted squared $dt$, but not from the last term just $d\phi^2$ there. Also, your $dr$ in the metric should be $dr^2$?

Comment: BTW have you actually tried to read the answer you linked to, or a more detailed answer here: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/19718/why-is-the-taub-nut-instanton-singular-at-%24-theta-pi%24?show=19750#a19750  ?

Comment: Typo edited, thanks. Anyway, no, they are not curvature singularities. I've checked a couple of invariants (my previous  not answered question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249115/curvature-invariants-in-general-relativity-and-singularities  is related)  and on the references I have they talk  about coordinate singularity.

Comment: I agree, this is a coordinate singularity. Curvature singularities occur when $V = 0$, similar to the Schwarzschild metric.